# Communication between app.component.html and app.component.ts

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, bootstrap-4

I have built an Angular form in my app.component.html file, and I am trying to submit the field inputs to an API via the app.component.ts file. How would I refer to the inputs from the .html file in the .ts file (where I am passing the data to an API)?

The submit button in the .html file is defined like this:

```
<button (click)="addCust(custJSON)" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!customerForm.form.valid">Submit</button>
```

Creating a JSON object out of all the input fields, also in the .html file:

```
<script>var custJSON = {{customerForm.value | json}};</script>
{{customerForm.value | json}}
```

The function, defined in my .ts file:

```
addCust(custJSON) {
  this.httpClient.post(`api url`,
  {
     custName: custJSON.custName,
     phone: custJSON.phone,
     etc
  })
  .subscribe(
    (data:any) => {
      console.log(data);
    }
  )
}
```

The error I get right now is that `custJSON` is undefined. Hardcoding the data in the addCust method works fine, but the goal is to upload input from the form to the API. How do I get data from the .html file to the .ts file?

EDIT: Here is the updated HTML for my form:

```
<div class="container">
<form ngNativeValidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(customerForm)" action="/action_page.php" name="myForm" #customerForm="ngForm">

<div class="form-group row">
<label for="custName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="custName" placeholder='Name' maxlength=100 required [(ngModel)]="model.custName" name="custName" #custName="ngModel" style="width: 40em">
    </div>
    <div [hidden]="custName.valid || custName.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
        Name is required
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
<label for="phone" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Phone</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input pattern=".{14,14}" type="number" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="011 1 111 222 3333" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" type = "number" minLength="14" maxLength="14" style="width: 18em" required [(ngModel)]="model.phone" name="phone" #phone="ngModel">
  </div>
<!-- <button class="addfields" type="button" >+</button> -->
<br><div [hidden]="phone.valid || phone.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
  Phone is required
</div>

  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
<label for="email" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email Address</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder='ab@cd.com' maxlength=64 required [(ngModel)]="model.email" name="email" #email="ngModel" style="width: 40em">
  </div>
<div [hidden]="email.valid || email.pristine"
     class="alert alert-danger">
  Email Address is required
</div>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!customerForm.form.valid">Submit</button>

  </form>


    <div [hidden]="!submitted">

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">JSON: <br></div>
    <pre id="result"></pre>
</div>

    <script>var custJSON = new JSON({{customerForm.value | json}});</script>
{{customerForm.value | json}} 

<br><br><br><button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="submitted=false">Edit</button><br><br><br><br><br>
```

EDIT: Updated ts file after making edits according to @penleychan:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Customer }    from '../customer';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {NgModule, Component} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Customer } from './customer';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { CustomerFormComponent } from './customer-form.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customer-form',
  templateUrl: './customer-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer-form.component.css']
})
export class CustomerFormComponent {
  custName:string;
  phone:number;
  email:string;

  model = new Customer('qt', 34823940903812, 't@t');

  submitted = false;

  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient){  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    console.log(form.value);

    this.submitted = true;

    this.httpClient.post<Customer>(`api url`,
      {
         custName: form.value.custName,
         phone: form.value.phone,
         email: form.value.email

         //this.result = form.value;
      })
      .subscribe(
        (data:any) => {
          console.log(data);
        }
      )
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: That's not exactly how you would want to submit a form, are you using NgForm or ReactiveForm?

Comment: Neither, it is mainly html wrapped in a <form> tag

Comment: This should help you out on regarding forms: https://angular.io/guide/forms you can try out the live example to understand how form submission works.

Comment: Thank you, I actually did start out by following that tutorial. I double-checked and `#customerForm="ngForm"` is defined in my form tag, if that is the only indication of using NgForm then I am. Apologies for my confusion! I am new to web dev.

Comment: Since you have that, you can just pass that in to your click event like so `addCust(customerForm)`. Then inside your `addCust()` you can get the values from your parameter you passed in.

Comment: I get an error message that the name column is null, despite filling in all fields before submitting

Comment: Perhaps can you edit your question and add your HTML of your form.

Comment: Sure, I just did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have `ngSubmit` you don't need the click event on your button. So simply just do this:

On your `<form>` for `ngSubmit` pass in the `NgForm` like so:

```
<form ngNativeValidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(customerForm)" action="/action_page.php" name="myForm" #customerForm="ngForm">
```

Remove `(click)="addCust(customerForm)"` from your button.

Now on your typescript for your component you should have and `onSubmit()` method, change it up a bit so now it will be:

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
   // Your logic...

   console.log(form.value); // Log your form outputs for testing purpose.
}
```

Here's a stackblitz for your convenience https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zcjvbt
(I removed the regex on the phone for testing)

Comment: Thank you for the stackblitz! I am still getting a null name column error, unfortunately. I've added my .ts file in the question as well, I suspect the form is taking values from the .ts file rather than the .html file.

Comment: @P.Po That's because if you look at your `data` you are posting, you are using the variables `custName`, `phone`, etc instead of your `model` which is what your ngForm is using. So instead of `this.custName` etc, replace those with `form.value.custName` or `model.custName` (should work too i think)

Comment: Using form.value: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
Using model: Model is not defined
Using customerForm.value: customerForm is not defined

Comment: Did you update your form as I mentioned above? Can you update your post with the latest HTML of your form?

Comment: Hmm, put `console.log(form.value);` at the top of your submit are you getting anything in the console?

Comment: The console displays all the fields, filled with the correct input values! But beneath it is still the name cannot be null error message.

Comment: Can you update your .ts file again but this time on how you are doing it.

Comment: Is `name cannot be null error message` coming from your server? From what i can see everything looks good... I am thinking it's your server, mismatching the object, so I assume it should be `{ name: form.value.custName, ... }`

Comment: Oh, man. That was it. Thank you, so, so much. The error message was coming from the server, yes, I have been using Chrome to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular forms.
For example:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
<input formControlName="cust_name" value="cust_name">
<button (click)="addCust()" type="submit">Submit</button>
     </form>
```

and in component.ts

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      cust_name: ['', Validators.required],
    });
}
addCust() {
          const val = this.form.value;
          this.httpClient.post(`api url`,
          {
            custName: val.cust_name,
          })
          .subscribe(
            (data:any) => {
              console.log(data);
            }
          )
        }
```

Comment: I am trying this, but it is giving me a "Can't resolve all parameters for CustomerFormComponent"  error. Currently looking into ways to clear this error.

Comment: did you import modules from @angular/forms? like this import { FormsModule, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, ReactiveFormsModule, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';